# Idiomatic Elixir to get nested list item?

Tags: elixir

I have this nested list items,

```
[["Bearer"], ["xxxyyyxxxx123"]] #  parsed from "Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"
```

and I just need to get the "xxxyyyxxxx123" value.

I am doing this now but I don't think it's idiomatic.

```
token = Regex.scan(~r/^Bearer|\w+/, header_content)
        |> List.flatten
        |> List.last
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way while keeping the same `Regex.scan/2` call is to use pattern matching.

```
iex(1)> header_content = "Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"
"Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"
iex(2)> [_, [token]] = Regex.scan(~r/^Bearer|\w+/, header_content)
[["Bearer"], ["xxxyyyxxxx123"]]
iex(3)> token
"xxxyyyxxxx123"
```

Unless I'm missing something, a more idiomatic way (and likely more efficient) to match this string (it's not functionality equivalent to your previous regex, but this might be correct for you) would be to use a different regex and pattern matching:

```
iex(4)> [_, token] = Regex.run(~r/Bearer\s*(.*)/, header_content)
["Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123", "xxxyyyxxxx123"]
iex(5)> token
"xxxyyyxxxx123"
```

Comment: Ignoring the whole word as a match is so common, that there is an option for that `:all_but_first`. `[token] = Regex.run(~r/Bearer\s*(.*)/, header_content, capture: :all_but_first)`

Comment: I would reach for `String.split/1` - `[_, token] = String.split(header_content)` but I'd be interested in knowing the opinions of those more knowledgeable.

Comment: I agree--using pattern matching in Elixir is almost always far more idiomatic than any other option.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just to match the string `"Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"`, there's another idiomatic Elixir way to do it.

```
iex(1)> "Bearer " <> token = "Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"
"Bearer xxxyyyxxxx123"
iex(2)> token
"xxxyyyxxxx123"
```

Note that you can match like this **only if the first part is a literal binary**. It's been documented as Marco [Kernel.<>/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.3/elixir/Kernel.html#%3C%3E/2).